# Не работает редирект с www на без www, если в адресе есть закрывающий слеш. Nginx

Tags: nginx, веб-сервер, ssl, https, redirect

На сервере настроен редирект для приведения адреса к такому виду:

```
https://domain.com/category/page
```

То есть идет переадресация на `https`, убирается `www` и закрывающий слэш.
На всех адресах отрабатывает корректно, следующие адреса приводятся к нужному виду:

```
https://domain.com/category/page/
https://www.domain.com/category/page
http://www.domain.com/category/page
http://www.domain.com/category/page/
http://domain.com/category/page/
http://domain.com/category/page
```

Но один вид адреса не проходит, это `https` с `www` и с закрывающий слэшем:

```
https://www.domain.com/category/page/
```

Ниже мой конфиг. Не могу понять что неверно. Выдает ошибку сертификата:
 `Подключение не защищено NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name domain.com default_server;

  root /var/www/domain;
  index index.php index.html;

  client_max_body_size 32m;

  location / {

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3333;
    proxy_read_timeout 1800;
    proxy_connect_timeout 1800;
    proxy_redirect http://localhost:3333 https://domain.com;

    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
  }

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/privkey.pem;
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name www.domain.com;
  return 301 https://domain.comy$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
  return 301 https://domain.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: У вас один и тот же server_name `www.domain.com` с одним и тем же `listen 443 ssl` принадлежит двум разным `server`ам — это вообще-то ошибка «conflicting server name» и так нельзя, начните с исправления этого

Comment: @andreymal ошибся, в первом блоке `server` не должно быть `www.domain.com`

Comment: Ну а теперь очевидно, что для `www.domain.com` сертификат не прописан, оттого он и INVALID (и слеш здесь вообще ни при чём)

Comment: Так же оказалось что сертификат был создан только для адреса без www

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ниже мой конфиг. Не могу понять что неверно. Выдает ошибку сертификата:
>   Подключение не защищено NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

По ssl информация передается в зашифрованном виде, в том числе и имя домена. В блоке

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name www.domain.com;
  return 301 https://domain.comy$request_uri;
}
```

не указан сертификат. Скопируйте сведения о сертификате из основного блока:

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name www.domain.com;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/privkey.pem;
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

  return 301 https://domain.comy$request_uri;
}
```